# error while serializing json using LoganSquare

Tags: android, json

i am trying to serialize json using `LoganSqure` parser

i have added following jars in my java build path

```
jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar
jackson-core-2.5.0.jar
logansquare-1.0.3.jar
logansquare-compiler-1.0.5.jar
```

and following is my model

```
@JsonObject
public class Image {

    /*
     * Standard field declaration.
     */
    @JsonField
    public String format;

}
```

but still  i am getting following error

```
07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313): Process: com.princepipe.fsa, PID: 9313
07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

    ComponentInfo{com.fsa/com.fsa.MainActivity}: com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.NoSuchMapperException: Class com.princepipe.model.Image could not be mapped to a JSON object. Perhaps it hasn't been annotated with @JsonObject?
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313): Caused by: com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.NoSuchMapperException: Class com.princepipe.model.Image could not be mapped to a JSON object. Perhaps it hasn't been annotated with @JsonObject?
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.LoganSquare.mapperFor(LoganSquare.java:130)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.LoganSquare.serialize(LoganSquare.java:80)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at com.princepipe.fsa.MainActivity.serialzieRequest(MainActivity.java:89)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at com.princepipe.fsa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     ... 11 more
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fsa.model.Image$$JsonObjectMapper
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at com.bluelinelabs.logansquare.LoganSquare.mapperFor(LoganSquare.java:126)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     ... 17 more
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fsa/model/Image$$JsonObjectMapper
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     ... 21 more
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.princepipe.model.Image$$JsonObjectMapper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fsa-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.fsa-1, /system/lib]]
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    07-16 10:30:09.360: E/AndroidRuntime(9313):     ... 21 more
```

Here is how i serialize

```
Image i = new Image();

        try {
            String data = LoganSquare.serialize(i);

            Log.e("Data ", data+"");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

JSON Request is pretty simple i am just tying to create a sample request

`{"format":"png"}`

Comment: Can you paste what the JSON you are trying to parse looks like

Comment: you didn't follow the instruction ... it looks like some kind of code weaver library ... AFAIK it should generate some code before compiling ... but it didn't(prolly because wrong setup) .... or ... proguard get rid of this generated code(still wrong setup)

Comment: please tell me what would be the right setup

Comment: i have tried the source from gitbub and try adding into my porject in eclipse but the result is same. m not able to identify whts the issue

Comment: @Hunt Did you find any solution?! Same problem here.

Comment: are you using eclipse or android studio ?

Comment: Same here. But I'm serializing an array.